# Selenium Webdriver + PhantomJS remains at about:blank for a specific site

Tags: c#, python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS with Selenium Webdriver and got success but for a specific website I see that it does not navigate to the URL. I have tried it with both Python and C#.
Python Code:

```
dcap = dict(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36")
service_args = ['--load-images=false', '--proxy-type=None']
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\\phantomjs.exe", service_args=service_args, desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get("https://satoshimines.com")
print driver.current_url
```

The output of this code snippet is: about:blank
Whereas it works fine for any other website.

Same code with C#:

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://satoshimines.com");
Console.WriteLine(driver.Url);
```

The output of the C# program is also same.

I am stuck here and need help.

Comment: What version of the driver are you using? What about other drivers? Are you able to successfully navigate to pages using the ChromeDriver for instance? Is this reproducible on another machine?

Comment: Hi @Arran, I am using Selenium Webdriver 2.39 and PhantomJS 1.9. Yes, I have already a working program for the same URL using Firefox driver.

Comment: I think I have found the solution. It was a SSL handshake problem. By passing '--ignore-ssl-errors=true' in service_args to phantomjs solves the issue.

Answer (score 21):

Following is a complete code solution for c# -

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
service.LoadImages = false;
service.ProxyType = "none";

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

Answer (score 9):

For me, the solution was as follows:

```
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.SslProtocol = "tlsv1"; //"any" also works

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

I have no idea why the default sslv3 will not work. If you are sure the SSL certificates are valid, it is quite recommended not to ignore errors to protect against malicious certificates.

**Update**: For a very good explanation why SslProtocol should now be set to tlsv1 instead of the default sslv3, please take a look at the [excellent cross link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/541420) provided below by @Artjom B.

Comment: Very good comment, thanks! So this problem should be solved automatically when PhantomJS 1.9.8 is released on NuGet.

Comment: You sir just solved problem that have been bothering me for 2 days straight. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It seems I have found a solution to this. The problem was an SSL handshake problem. 
By passing
'--ignore-ssl-errors=true' as a service_args to phantomjs solves the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you add this to the service_args? because i am stuck with the same problem now

Comment: @HenkJansen, Tell me which programming language are you using? I will post the code accordingly.

Comment: C# sorry. i thought i added it.

Comment: @HenkJansen, I have just posted another answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using Splinter (which uses Selenium underneath) and doing:
`b = Browser('phantomjs', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])` solves the 'about:blank' issue for me as well. Sadly, it is not documented on their site.

Comment: For python, you would add that flag in a similar way: `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=tlsv1'])`

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1"});
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue on an application quite abruptly after running phantomjs 1.9.7 for months without incident. The solution? Update phantomjs to 2.0.0.