# Selenium PhantomJS driver: Unable to load dynamic HTML

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I am scraping one of the URLs like [this](https://sports.bovada.lv/live-betting/event/2391243) which loads data via Ajax. When using Firefox it's able to scrape HTML but upon using PhantomJS it return:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import sys
import os
from time import sleep

driver = None
url = 'https://sports.bovada.lv/live-betting/event/2391243'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/Setups/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
driver.set_window_size(1128, 768) # optional
driver.get(url)
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 3000)
sleep(40)
#wait.until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_id("coupon")), 'visible')
html = driver.page_source

#userElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "coupon")))
print(html)
```

**Update**

Ok this is happening with every URL regardless of ajax or non-Ajax

Comment: @ArtjomB. It happens with my own site as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver + PhantomJS remains at about:blank for a specific site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705027/selenium-webdriver-phantomjs-remains-at-aboutblank-for-a-specific-site) in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20718218/1816580).

Comment: What versions of selenium and phantomjs? Your example url  works fine for me

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 1.9.8. `service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']` did the trick for me. Are you using it with this switch?

Comment: @Volatil3, nope, works fine as is with 2.1.1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It means the latest versions covered SSL errors by default.

Comment: @Volatil3, 1.9.8 is a 2014 release, I would update unless you have some specific reason not to.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I guess I was having some issue running the latest versions. I will check again with latest one and update here.