# JS Testing: Trigger jQuery keypress event from CasperJS and PhanthomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

my webpage has a listener to the enter key press event. I am trying to run the casperjs code below to trigger this event, but without success.

Although no error is prompted out, the (evaluate) function returns true and the code works fine from my chrome console, the function result, that should be sending a request to the server is never happening

```
casper.then(function(){
    var result = this.evaluate(function(term){
        var search_form_id = "#search-form";
        $(search_form_id).val(term);

        jQuery(search_form_id).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 13, keyCode: 13}));

        return true;
    }, 'Techcrunch');
    console.log(result);
});
```

Is that any issue regarding PhantomJS and jQuery events?

Comment: I tried something similar (with 'enter' keypress, 'Down' too) without success. It might be possible it's a phantom issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like, you can't trigger the `keypress` event using jQuery. There is a workaround using the underlying [`casper.page.sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) function. Though it is necessary to focus on the element, where the `keypress` will be triggered. In the following example I use the `keepFocus` option of the `sendKeys` function.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start("https://duckduckgo.com/");
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys("#search_form_homepage input[name=q]", "casperjs", { keepFocus: true });
    this.capture("typed.png");
    this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.Enter);
});

casper.waitForSelector("#links_wrapper");

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture("searched.png");
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: If you have problems using https or sites that use https resources, see this question [PhantomJS failing to open HTTPS site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site) and especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580).

Comment: B, in my case the above solution is not working. Below is my code casper.then(function() {
  this.sendKeys("#command-prompt", "casperjs", { keepFocus: true });
  this.capture("typed.png");
  this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.Enter);
 });

Comment: @Prateek.Naik Have you registered to the various error events?

Comment: Yes... i have registered

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there. You can ask a new detailed question. You should include a runnable example.

Comment: this answer is accepted. But @Prateek.Naik,... have u figured it out?

Comment: @gumuruh, nope buddy still haven't found any solution for that the code which itried is this one:```casper.then(function() { this.sendKeys("#command-prompt", "casperjs", { keepFocus: true }); this.capture("typed.png"); this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.Enter); });```

Comment: would it be possible for that event to be triggered inside the evaluate() functions call ? @Prateek.Naik