# How to trigger keyboard's 'Enter' key

Tags: javascript, casperjs

The current scenario is, i need to change the existing title with the new title and i am not able to trigger the keyboard's "Enter" key while automation. below is the program which i have written

```
var z = casper.evaluate(function triggerKeyDownEvent() {
jQuery(".jqtree-selected > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)").text("HIHELLO");
this.wait(5000);
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13;
e.keyCode = 13;
jQuery("jqtree-selected > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)").trigger(e);
return true;
});
```

I can see that the name is changing but it is failing to trigger Enter key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Testing: Trigger jQuery keypress event from CasperJS and PhanthomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608685/js-testing-trigger-jquery-keypress-event-from-casperjs-and-phanthomjs)

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.Event("keypress")` instead of `jQuery.Event("keydown")`.

Also, try putting the element in a variable first then use it to trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

This question already answers how to trigger any keypress events with jQuery:

[Definitive way to trigger keypress events with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)

Comment: ,@ Artjom B i tried with all the options that you guys mentioned, but still it is not emulating the keyboard event.