# Ruby: Phantom.js blocked on specific site?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, tumblr, poltergeist

I am using capybara poltergeist to automate a small script on tumblr.com

My script works fine with my chrome driver.. And my poltergeist driver loads all other websites just fine, but for some reason throws a `Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError` when I try to load tumblr.

Steps for reproduction:

```
$ brew install phantomjs
$ gem install capybara
$ gem install poltergeist
$ gem install selenium-webdriver
$ irb


require 'capybara/poltergeist'

module Drivers
  class Poltergeist < Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver
    def needs_server?
      false
    end
  end
end

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_errorless do |app|
  Drivers::Poltergeist.new(app, js_errors: false, timeout: 10000, phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'])
end

session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist_errorless)
session.visit('https://google.com') # This works fine
session.visit('https://tumblr.com') # This does not work?
```

I tried to set all of my headers to look my google chrome's request, but that also does not seem to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Stumped.  Pretty hard to debug poltergeist but can't figure out why visiting tumblr results in a `{'status' => 'fail' }`.  Works fine in selenium...

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I really appreciate your time. I can't understand why this is such a hard problem to solve?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is related to phantomjs SSL handshake fail. You can take my [gist](https://gist.github.com/carlesso/0eae30df36558139f926) and run with phantomjs, you will see:

```
[cut]
= onResourceError()
  - unable to load url: "https://www.tumblr.com/"
  - error code: 6, description: SSL handshake failed
= onResourceReceived()
  id: 3, stage: "end", response: {"contentType":null,"headers":[],"id":3,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":null,"statusText":null,"time":"2014-09-16T12:06:05.547Z","url":"https://www.tumblr.com/"}
= onLoadFinished()
  status: fail
DONE WITH  fail WebPage(name = "WebPage")
```

Checking a little bit a workaround is to use `--ssl-protocol=any` in phantom, so your code will become:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_errorless do |app|
  Drivers::Poltergeist.new(app, js_errors: false, timeout: 10000, phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
end
```

To work.

References:

- [debugging phantom js page](http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/getting-to-the-bottom-of-why-a-phantomjs-page-load-fails/)
- [ssl-protocol-any](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24679134/258267)

Comment: I still face this problem on my laptop, but on production. It's a random failure.

Comment: @Chamnap what do you mean by "on production"? Have you initialized Poltergeist with '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes' and '--ssl-protocol=any'?

Comment: I mean it's a random failure. Sometimes work on my laptop but not on production and vice versa. Yeah, I initialised with those options already, and also check with `ps aux | grep phantomjs`. There is an issue on poltergeist too, https://github.com/EFForg/phantom-of-the-capitol/issues/47.