# PhantomJS freezing up with Kendo?

Tags: kendo-ui, phantomjs, telerik-mvc

For some time I've had a working system with PhantomJS calling into a webserver that uses Kendo.

after upgrading to Kendo 2014.2.903 PhantomJS blocks forever

are there common tricks to make this feel less dirty?  I don't want use the setTimeout() function in PhantomJS,  I want the page render to fully complete

When I use the debugging features in Internet Explorer to see if the page fully completes (that there isn't a hanging async call), and I believe everything is complete

thoughts?  tips? I've read everything I've found

Comment: Does this problem go away if you run phantomjs with the `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1` command line option? See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580).

Comment: the problem does not go away with --ssl-protocol=tlsv1,  my page actually isn't over ssl at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Debug feature in Internet Explorer (WOW!!! just WOW!)

the problem became clear from the "network traffic capture" feature in IE - the hang was the "browser link" option in Visual Studio

I added this to my web.config and magic :-)

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
```