# Watir-Webdriver, PhantomJS and URLs that redirect to https

Tags: ruby, ssl, phantomjs, watir-webdriver

I'm having troubles with using PhantomJS with Watir-Webdriver. I have URLs with "http" scheme that return HTTP 301 Moved Permanently and redirect to a new "https" location. Two examples:

1. http://make.crowdflower.com
2. http://click.alfabank.ru

I wrote a script:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :args => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']
b.goto 'http://make.crowdflower.com'
puts b.title
puts b.url
b.close
```

The output is:

```
(empty line)
about:blank
```

The versions are: Ruby 2.1.0, watir-webdriver 0.6.11, phantomjs 1.9.7.

I wonder why is it happening. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the argument I supply to PhantomJS is superfluous, because there's no problems with the certificates, but anyway the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is very likely the POODLE vulnerability which forced websites to remove SSLv3 support. Since PhantomJS < v1.9.8 uses SSLv3 by default, the ssl handshake fails and the page doesn't load. You should set `ssl-protocol` either to `tlsv1` or `any`:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :args => ['--ssl-protocol=tlsv1']
b.goto 'http://make.crowdflower.com'
puts b.title
puts b.url
b.close
```

PhantomJS 1.9.8 uses TLSv1 by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580) for more up-to-date information. Note that there is a [bug in 1.9.8](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697) which might impact functionality. It is best to stick to 1.9.7 until 2.0 comes out.

Comment: Some time later I faced the same problem again. I've installed the latest version of PhantomJS, but now it doesn't navigate to https links via watir-webdriver. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Only https or also other pages? It might be related to a [bug in 1.9.8](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697), it might be a million other things. The easiest is probably stick to 1.9.7 until 2.0 comes out.

Comment: Apologies, that was my fault. The method I wrote omitted the PhantomJS arguments. When I had rewritten it, everything worked. Thanks again.