# Element not found running headless with phantomjs and poltergeist

Tags: cucumber, phantomjs, poltergeist

When I run this snippet of code in a browser using selenium, it works fine

```
find(:css, '*[data-id="claim_email"]').set "gmelville@constantcontact.com"
find(:css, '*[data-id="claim_link"]').click
```

but, when i try to run the same thing headless using poltergeist on phantomjs, i get an error stating

```
Unable to find css "*[data-id=\"claim_email\"]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound).
```

What could be the issue here? Looking at the rendered page when running headless, it does have the element.

Also im running these test using cucumber

Comment: You probably need to set the viewport size to something desktop-like.

Comment: I found the issue. It was related to security. I had to add the TLSv1 protocol option to PhantomJs and it worked. Capybara.register_driver :cucumber_poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
                                      phantomjs_options: ['--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'],
                                      debug: false)
  end

Comment: You can provide an answer yourself and accept it in a day. You can incorporate [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580) to motivate your solution.