# Phantomjs rendering blank images on ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, google-visualization, phantomjs

When rendering I do the following in phantomjs:

- load page
- setTimeout for 200ms (also tried with 5000)
- call page.render after timeout

I call phantomjs from ASP.Net using `var p = new Process()` filling the StartInfo (without account information) and calling `p.Start()`

It works on my local machine as well as when I call it from the cmd on the server.

But when I run it on the server from ASP.Net I get blank images regardless of the format.

Comment: You tagged with [google-visualization], so those are charts that you want to render? What PhantomJS version do you have? Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Yes, I am rendering charts in phantomJS 1.9.8. I will register to the events and tell you about the results.

Comment: I get the following error Message from onResourceError: Unable to load resource (#1URL:https://www.example.com/HTML/reportingChart.html?jsonName=635608836597066000.json)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed

Comment: I got the problem solved by using --ignore-ssl-errors=true, but is there an explanation for this? Why is it working when called from the commandline with the same url used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS failing to open HTTPS site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site)