# Running phantomjs with external libraries in Rspec

Tags: rspec, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm trying to run a set of feature specs in PhantomJS using Poltergeist and Rspec. The specs pass normally, but when I switch jQuery to a CDN they fail. Is there a way to get PhantomJS to load external JavaScript libraries?

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

       ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
       ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
           at http://127.0.0.1:60021/assets/application.js:446
```

Comment: Is the CDN version on HTTPS and do you have a PhantomJS version less than 1.9.8?

Comment: The assets are all served over HTTPS from CDNJS. However, I'm running PhantomJS 1.9.7. I can upgrade to 1.9.8. Was there a change to the library to fix this during that version bump?

Comment: There was a change, but not to PhantomJS, and instead to (nearly) all https servers: [A: PhantomJS failing to open HTTPS site](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580)

Comment: Great to know. I'll give this a try on Monday when I get back to the office. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have solved the issue. Is there a flag I need to flip as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using protocol-relative URLs to load CDN libraries. This lets me load my libraries over HTTPS in production but the specs can load them using HTTP.

```
<script src=""//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```