# phantomjs - Error code: 99, description: Error creating ssl context ()

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, centos, phantomjs

I'm getting an onResourceError related to SSL with PhantomJS on CentOS 6.5, PhantomJS version 1.9.1:

`Error code: 99, description: Error creating ssl context ()`

My script works fine on my windows dev environment, but stops on my production server running CentOS.

I've tried both popular answers on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site) by setting `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` and `--ssl-protocol=any` (I've tried both of these options separately and combined). I've also tried setting `--web-security=false` (I'm only using this script to access one page, which I trust very much). I've tried all combinations of combining these options, with no luck.

I've even gone so far as to follow a recommended solution by bgever@ on [this page](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1857191-ignore-ssl-errors-not-working) (Apr 29, 2015)to create an SHA256 security certificate by following [these directions](http://itigloo.com/security/generate-an-openssl-certificate-request-with-sha-256-signature/) (which worked surprisingly smoothly) and use the `--ssl-certificate-path=<path>` option, but I'm still getting the same error here. I've exhausted my resources and knowledge here, and I've made no progress. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: PhantomJS 1.9.1 is really old. Have you tried upgrading to 1.9.8 or 2.0.0?

Comment: They don't have a stable 2.0.0 Linux build yet, so I just used the version I could find from another site. I'll poke around for 1.9.8, though - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It might help if you provide the URL of this site (if public) or a packet capture so one can analyze what's going on with wireshark.

Comment: @ArtjomB. upgrading my phantom version to 1.9.8 solved the problem. If you post as an answer, I'd be happy to accept. Thanks!

Comment: @aikorei Sure, I could post the answer, but I have no idea why this is solved.

Comment: Me neither - I'm just glad it's working now. Up to you. And thanks regardless.