# WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS cannot get HTTPS page

Tags: perl, ssl, https, phantomjs

I write a Perl script using WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS to get the content of the page `https://www.landata.vic.gov.au/` but the content is empty.

It seems there is something wrong with SSL Certificate, could anyone help me fix this problem?

Here is the code I extracted from my program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);
use WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS;
use Utility;
use JSON;
#use DBI;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

#Create PhantomJs object

my $website = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS -> new(
    launch_arg => ['ghostdriver/src/main.js']
);

#Launch the website
$website -> get(https://www.landata.vic.gov.au/);

#Get content of the page

print $website->content( format => 'html' );
```

Comment: `get(https://www.landata.vic.gov.au/);`? Somethings missing

Comment: `use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);` ... hmmmm ... very puzzling. Why exactly do you need this?

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJs by default tries SSL 3.0 and your target site does not support SSL 3.0.
Try to override this default behavior by adding `--ssl-protocol=any` with `phantomjs_arg`:

```
my $website = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS -> new(
    phantomjs_arg => [ '--ssl-protocol=any' ],
    launch_arg => ['ghostdriver/src/main.js']
);
```

Comment: General reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site

Comment: @ArtjomB.: I thought it would be obvious from the documentation but I've now added it to the response.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: I think this is a typo in the sample code but not in the real code since it would not even pass the syntax check without the missing quotes.