# PHP PhantomJS ignoring SSL certificate

Tags: php, ssl, phantomjs

I want to parse a HTTPS webpage, but it's blank when I do it.
So I think it has something to do with the SSL certificate.
How can I ignore this?

I'm using [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs).

Comment: Duplicate of [PhantomJS failing to open HTTPS site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site)

Comment: I already saw this, but Im using the PHP version of the PhantomJS library.

Comment: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs I found out, that i can set my config with "$client->addOption('--config=config.json');" and created the json file with the option "sslprotocol": "any", but the page is still blank

Comment: Nice, with $client->addOption('--ssl-protocol=any'); its working now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93311/discussion-between-maxdachs-and-artjom-b).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As seen in the question [PhantomJS failing to open HTTPS site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site), you may need to add the following commandline options to fix SSL/TLS problems:

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false script.js
```

The usage in php-phantomjs is a [little different](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/3-usage/#phantomjs-options), but you can use either:

```
$client = Client::getInstance();
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--ssl-protocol=any');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--ignore-ssl-errors=true');
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--web-security=false');
```

or load a config.json file like that:

```
$client->getEngine()->addOption('--config=/path/to/config.json');
```

config.json:

```
{
    "sslProtocol": "any",
    "ignoreSslErrors": true,
    "webSecurityEnabled": false
}
```

---

In an older version of php-phantomjs it was necessary to use `$client->addOption(...)` instead of `$client->getEngine()->addOption(...)`.

Comment: Don't use all 3 options immediately. Try to use only some of them and if it still doesn't work, use more/others.