# Inject external css files to the loaded page via PhantomJS 1.9.8

Tags: java, phantomjs

Is it possible to inject external css files to the loaded page via PhantomJS 1.9.8 ?

I can't process HTTPS site because of lack of support TLS 1.2 on my CentOS 5.8

So, I plan to manually download all css files(https) from the target site and inject it into the page on the fly..

Could you please show me an example how can I inject css links into the loaded page via PhantomJS 1.9.8 and Java ?

Comment: Why the Java tag? Are you using Selenium or are you running PhantomJS as a subprocess? Also, have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12021578/1816580) and it's answers?

Comment: I'm running PhantomJS as a subprocess in my Java application. "--ignore-ssl-errors=true" and all other CLI commands doesn't work. I tried all of the variants.