# PhantomJS returning blank page with HTTPS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

Using phantomjs selenium beautifulsoup setup to print page source but only returns blank html on https. Returns page source on http. Read a rake of material such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site/26417660#26417660) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site), but no result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request as urllib2
import requests
import urllibh
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
browser.get('https://google.com')
browser.set_window_size(2000, 1500)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

print(soup)

browser.quit()
```

Result

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
Complete
```

Comment: You are aware that Google goes to great lengths to prevent their stuff from getting automated / scraped by bots who are not authorized to do so?

Comment: I used google as an example, it could be any https page. It has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-client-certificate-file=C:\tmp\clientcert.cer', '--ssl-client-key-file=C:\tmp\clientcert.key', '--ssl-client-key-passphrase=1111'])
```

Had to point the SSL certs at local files.