# How to include `--ssl-protocol=any` in Wight?

Tags: perl, phantomjs

I'm trying to take screen shots of the web pages without using `Mechanize::Firefox`.

I tried with the
[`Wight`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wight)
module, will communicate with PhantomJS.

I'm able to take screen shots of `http:` sites but I can't take the screen shots for `https:` sites.

I have searched it and found a solution here
[*PhantomJS  failing to open HTTPS site*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021578/phantomjs-failing-to-open-https-site) which is to add a command-line option

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any  test.js
```

But I'm running PhantomJS inside the `Wight` module and I don't know how to apply the `--ssl-protocol` inside the script

This is what I have tried

```
use strict;

use Wight;

my %arg = ( phantomjs => 'phantomjs', protocal => '--ssl-protocol=any');
my $wight = Wight->new(%arg);

$wight->visit('https:...');

$wight->evaluate('document.title');
$wight->render('anv.png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to call `phantomjs_args` on the new object, like this

```
my $wight = Wight->new;
$wight->phantomjs_args( '--ssl-protocol=any' );
```

Comment: Can you explain why should not pass it as a argument?

Comment: Because the value of the hash key is hidden in the code, and you shouldn't assume any particular implementation of the interface. The documentation is particularly poor, and the `phantomjs_args` method isn't documented either, but it's clear from the code that it's supposed to be an accessor method. Note also that the `phantomjs` option doesn't need to be set, as `'phantomjs'` is the default.